# Return from a callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Javascript coding and have looked for this information in many places but haven't found one working solution, hence I am posting this question here.

In a for loop I am trying to request POIs in a region (leg of the route) using -

```
service.search(request, callback);
```

where request includes parameters like location and type of POI queried. I have implemented the callback function as below -

```
function callback(myResults, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert('myResults: ' + myResults.length);
        // entire remaining code here, where I do some processing on the POIs.
    }   
}
```

This code is working and at each leg of the route I get to see the POIs, and also number of POIs is displayed using alert.

My issue is that I do not want to process the "myResult" here for each leg, but collect all the results for the entire route (made up of many legs) and then do the processing at once.

1. I first thought of creating a global variable ("myPOIs") and append "myResults" at each leg and once the entire route is parsed, then to process this myPOIs, but I am not able (or I dont know how) to append this myResults to a global variable myPOIs.
2. The other option, I was thinking of is getting a return (myResults) from the callback function and then collecting (appending) all the results.

The only difference between 1 and 2 is that, in 1, its a global variable I will be appending myResults to within the if condition, and in 2, if the if condition is true then return the myResults to the service.search and then collect the results there.

I tried using myPOIs.push(myResults) and a few other options, but when I check the myPOIs.length it is always null. I really dont know how to get the myResults out of the callback function.

Any suggestion/ throughts/ help will be very useful for me.

And I want to use only javascript and nothing else for this.

Thanks a lot in advance,
axs

Comment: Could you also add in the for loop code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are calling the search something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    service.search(legs[i], callback);
}
```

then you can do this by keeping track of all the results, and the number of times you've been called back:

```
var callbacksOutstanding = legs.length;
var allPlaces = [];
var callback = function(legPlaces, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        allPlaces.push.apply(allPlaces, legPlaces);
    } 
    if (--callbacksOustanding === 0) {
        processPlaces(allPlaces);
    }
};
for (var i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    service.search(legs[i], callback);
}
```

Where `processPlaces` is some function you've written to process the complete array of `PlaceResult` objects.

Now the three `var` statements there are *not* global variables if this is all wrapped in a function (as it should be), because in Javascript you can and should define functions inside other functions. And if you do so, the inner functions will have access to variables in the outer functions. So for me this might look like this:

```
function findAndProcessPlaces(legs) {
    var callbacksOutstanding = legs.length;
    var allPlaces = [];
    var callback = function(legPlaces, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            allPlaces.push.apply(allPlaces, legPlaces);
        } 
        if (--callbacksOustanding === 0) {
            processPlaces(allPlaces);
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        service.search(legs[i], callback);
    }
}
```

NB: The `allPlaces.push.apply` line performs an in-place concatenation of one array to another. You could also write:

```
allPlaces = allPlaces.concat(legPlaces)
```

at this point.

Comment: Thanks, this method worked and solved my problem. As callbacks are asynchronous and do not necessarily follow a sequential process, so one has to track the number of callbacks and wait till all callbacks are done. Your var callbacksOutstanding was a very good suggestion and I guess this was the key to solving this problem. Also the second most important thing is allPlaces.push(legPlaces) does not work. I dont know why, but you have to use allPlaces.push.apply(allPlaces, legPlaces); to append to the array which was also very critical in solving this problem. I didnt try concat approach.

Comment: Just a quick note - In the final function which is created, the variable var allPlaces = []; should be outside the function findAndProcessPlaces as I want all the results from all legs have to be stored in allPlaces.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable:

```
var POIResults = [];
```

In your function callback

```
POIResults.push(myResults);
```

Later at your convenience, call a function which iterates the array

```
function checkResults(){
 for(var i = 0; i < POIResults.length; i++){
  //TODO: check POIResults[i]
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but had tried this approach. Infact this was the first thing I tried as I mentioned in my problem statement. As I now figured out from lan's accepted answer below, this approach does not work because callbacks are asynchronous and you never know when all the results are pushed onto POIResults. Also for some reason just POIResults.push(myResults); does not work, it has to be POIResults.push.apply(POIResults, myResults); as suggested in the post answer below

Comment: @axs - As discussed in length in Ian's answer, I am assuming you made an outer global, but not a true global array. Asynchronous pushing into an array works given the right conditions - mainly that the array is a truly global variable.

Comment: Thanks Travis. As you noticed, I have created an outer global array, but how do I create a true global array?

Answer (score 0):

An array defined out side the call back and within theright scope should do the trick. Can you post the code with the global array approach?

Comment: Thanks, but this global array defined outside alone does not do the trick for callback function. Have a look at lan's answer below which solved the problem. In the final function which he has created, just remove var allPlaces = []; and put it outside, it makes the variable global and holds all the results.